# Retrofit 1.9 - Same variable name, different JSON type - CONVERSION exception

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a JSON key called `buttons`
This JSON key can take either forms, a JSON Array OR a JSON Object.
However, since I'm using Pojos, I can define only one type of `buttons` variable.
Either `Buttons buttons` (for JSON object) **or** `List<Buttons> buttons` (for JSON Array).
But this causes retrofit's `CONVERSION` exception if the run time type of `buttons` does not match my variable type.
What should be my approach to this situation? Can Retrofit 2 solve this problem?

Code :

When `buttons` is of type JSON array

```
buttons: [
{
title: "key1",
value: "value1"
},
{
title: "key2",
value: "value2"
},
{
title: "key3",
value: "value3"
}
],
```

When `buttons` is of type JSON object

```
buttons: {
title: "key",
value: "value"
},
```

Comment: You should consider using the List/Array in your POJO and if you only need one button object you can have the same List/Array just with one item in it. Can you share the sample of your JSON?

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla I've edited the question. Please check.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla Yes, you are right. That is one possible solution. however, in that case, the changes would have to be done on the server side. Can there be some client side fix to this?

Comment: Since you will only know after receiving the JSON payload from server, you may have to check for the specific key "`buttons`" - and based on its type (JSON-Array or JSON-Object) you can special POJO to parse the payload - I do think it might be best to use Generics to represent the type of your  `buttons` variable in the POJO.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation better solution to create [JsonDeserializer](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)

You can use something like this:

```
public class TestDeser implements JsonDeserializer<ButtonList>{
@Override
public ButtonList deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    final ButtonList list = new ButtonList();
    if (json.isJsonArray()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < json.getAsJsonArray().size(); i++) {
            final Button btn = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonArray().get(i), Button.class);
            list.buttons.add(btn);
        }
    } else {
        final Button btn = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject(), Button.class);
        list.buttons.add(btn);
    }
    return list;
}}
```

In this example you can see how to check input json is it JsonArray or JsonObject and proceed with default logic of parsing Button.

You can register this deserializer as follows below:

```
new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ButtonList.class, new TestDeser()).create();
```